# How to keep the CSS transform animation proportional to the screen width?

Tags: javascript, css

Consider this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/utzfbjed/

code here:

```css
.image {
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.image:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(12em, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(14em, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(14em, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(14em, 0);
    transform: translate(14em, 0);
  }
.container {
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
}
.a {
  aspect-ratio : 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container > * {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='a'>
  </div>
  <img class='image' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Red_circle.svg/200px-Red_circle.svg.png" alt="Dimage">
</div>
```

There is a small red ring in the center of the black circle. When hovering on the ring, it moves towards the right edge of the circle.

My questions are, **when adjusting the screen width**:

1. How to make sure the red ring always appear on the same position on the edge of the circle after the animation?
2. The black circle shrinks as screen width changes. How to make sure the red ring is proportional to the black circle? i.e. larger when black circle gets larger, smaller when black circle gets smaller.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, you don't need vendor prefixes for [`transition`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition) or [`transform`](https://caniuse.com/transforms2d).

Comment: Would [vw units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#:~:text=1%25%20of%20the%20viewport%27s%20width.) work for you? (You have to scroll down a little way on that page I linked)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `position: absolute` on the ring *inside* the black circle, then size and move it proportionally in relation to the parent?

```css
.image {
  width: 50%;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  ;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.a:hover .image {
  left: 100%
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
}

.a {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='a'>
    <img class='image' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Red_circle.svg/200px-Red_circle.svg.png" alt="Dimage">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: In my real app the `<div class='a'></div>` is a HTML `input` element so cannot change the HTML structure in the snippet, `<div class='a'>` has to be parallel with the `img`

Comment: Then wrap both in an inline container and that can have position relative.